# Align Button in a ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, xml, view

I designed a simple registration screen like below.

[image: image1]

And here is the xml code for it.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".RegisterActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout2"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/reg_display_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="hint"
        android:text="Display name" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout3"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout2">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/reg_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="hint"
        android:text="Email" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout4"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout3">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/reg_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="hint"
        android:text="Password" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/reg_create_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
    android:text="Create account"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout4"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="132dp" />
```

However, when I run the app the button is not aligned in the center.

[image: image2]

Any ideas how to fix that?

Thanks,
Theo.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add contraints to your views to center them in the parent layout

```
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
```

On each view, your button don't have these constraints

Answer (score 1):

You need to add constraints to achieve your desired layout as follows:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/reg_create_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:text="Create account"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout4"
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this .. change only button.

```
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".RegisterActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout2"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/reg_display_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="hint"
        android:text="Display name" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout3"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout2">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/reg_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="hint"
        android:text="Email" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout4"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout3">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/reg_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="hint"
        android:text="Password" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/reg_create_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
    android:text="Create account"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout4"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="132dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"` and `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` will make the button floating over other views

Answer (score 0):

Your button appears centered in Android Studio's preview because of this attribute:

```
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="132dp"
```

These `tools` attributes have no effect at runtime, though. To center the button, you should constrain its start and end to the parent's start and end:

```
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
```